# windows spanned volume fails after sleep (requires restart)

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, disk-utility

I have a 4TB spanned volume in windows 7 professional 64bit (2TB x2 and a single 1TB). It works great after a boot/reboot, but if I put the computer to sleep, it fails to mount/the spanned volume on wake. A restart fixes it.

This is a software spanned volume set up with the plain old windows disk utility.

Anyone have a fix? I put my computer to sleep much more often than a full shutdown, so obviously this is annoying.

Answer (score 1):

Some large drives tend to have a tough time initiating on time.  Earlier SSDs also had this problem.  There is a hotfix you can try.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/977178

Comment: No luck. same problem